# C# Text typing error recognition

Tags: c#, design-patterns, text

I'm working on importing a list of cities and based on the values in  this list, do further actions. However, this list is manually typed, which makes it very error prone.

I'm wondering if there is some sort of typing error recognition (like Google uses 'did you mean x?').

I tried checking for parts of the city text, but that creates more errors than it solves (because a part of the city can also occur as a part in another city).

The good thing is, that I have a list of correct cities in memory, so perhaps it can be matched with a pattern?

My question is: is there a framework of subframework within dotNet that deals with these issues? 
If there isn't, could somebody point me in the right direction?

Here's an example of unique values from a manually typed list (fields marked with X are incorrect and should be mapped to the correct one):

```
GDANSK
HELSINGBORG
HRADEC KRALOVE
HRADEC KRALOVE 7    x
HRADEC KRALOW       x
HYLLYKALLIO
JARVSO   
JERVSO              x
KATOWICE
KOTKA
KRAKOW
KULJO
LOIMAA
LULEA
MINSK
MINSK CEZ           x
MOLNDAL
NORRKOPING
NORROPING           x
NYBORG
NYIERGYHAZA
NYIREGYHAZA         x
OSLO
OSTRAVA
OULU
PILZEN              x
PLZEN
POZNAN
PRAHA
PRESOV
PUNANE
RIGA
RISKOV              x
RISSKOV
RODDING
SANDEFJOR           x
SANDEFJORD
SARPSBORG
ST PETERSBURG
```

Comment: This looks interesting: http://blog.faroo.com/2012/06/24/1000x-faster-spelling-correction-source-code-released/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose some kind of edit distance based matching. The Levenshtein distance is widely used in spell checkers and string matching algorithms:

Have a look at this [wikipedia article on Levenshtein_distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Here's a link to a [C# implementation](http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein)

What you want to do is, in the absence of an exact match, show the top N nearest Levenshtein matches found in your list of known cities.

Comment: Great for small data sets... starts getting very expensive as you scale up.

Comment: @spender Fair point, but you can always speed things up by only including first letter matches in your search, words of similar length, etc, to reduce the work needed. And if it's just checking a list of known cities, it's probably not going to be too much of a problem.

Comment: Although very complicated (perhaps too complex for what I'm trying to achieve), this should be marked as the answer.